# Posting bigger URL thumbnails using API

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api

Recently Facebook introduced a bigger thumbnails for posted links. It's described in [this article](http://www.insidefacebook.com/2013/01/14/facebook-gives-links-more-prominence-in-news-feed-with-3x-larger-image-preview/).

But when I post to Facebook via Graph API, it creates small thumbnails though images I submit are bigger then 154x154 pixels. Posting directly via web interface works but I can't make it work through API.

Does somebody know if it's even possible to post links with bigger thumbnails via API? And if possible, how?

Thanks.